# Batch File to execute all .exe in a folder with timer

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've searched over this website and i know now how to excecute all .exe in a folder, and this is how i can do that (with batch file .bat) :

```
for /r "." %%a in (*.exe) do start "" "%%~fa"
```

Is there a way to execute them with a timer (2s for instance) between each .exe file ?

Comment: Do you want to *start* the executables in two-seconds intervals (so are they even allowed to run in parallel?), or do you want the next executable two seconds *after* the previous one has been terminated?

Comment: good question, i want to start the second one after 2secondes whether the first one finished or not, but i got my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /r "." %%a in (*.exe) do start "" "%%~fa"&timeout /t 2 >nul
```

`&` separates commands, >nul directs the `timeout` conversation to the bit-bucket so it isn't seen.

Answer (score 2):

2 options to produce a time out in batch are:

1. use `timeout /t SEC` where you replace `SEC` with the seconds you want it to time. Add the `/nobreak` option if you don't want the user to stop the timer by pressing any key. But be careful with this one: it doesn't guarantee a `SEC` seconds timer, it only guarentees it will make the system sleep for a timeinterval **between `SEC` and `SEC - 1` seconds**
2. A second more accurate option is to use `ping -n S 127.0.0.1 > nul`. As there is 1 second between each ping this will result in a **timeout of `S-1` seconds**

So for 2 seconds you could do:

```
for /r "." %%a in (*.exe) do (
    start "" "%%~fa"
    timeout /t 2 /nobreak
    REM Or ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul`
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `timeout` command. To wait 2 seconds, just use this between each of the .exe files.

```
timeout /T 2
```